# Chirality and Optical activity

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality, optical-properties

Do all chiral objects rotate the plane of polarization of EM waves? For example my hand is chiral, will it rotate the plane of polarization of EM waves of suitable wavelength?

Comment: "optical activity" is a problematic term if only because it implies EM radiation in the *visible* range. Unfortunately there isn't a simple general term. Though you could say, "can chiral macroscopic objects rotate the plane of EM waves of a suitable wavelength?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will, provided you have a billion of it. (One molecule does not rotate much, after all.) Also, each should come without the rest of the body, or at least without the other hand, otherwise that would make a racemic mixture. (I'll leave the grisly details to the reader's imagination.) Also, each hand should form the same gesture, otherwise the destructive interference will ruin the effect.

Also, light of suitable wavelength would be [microwave radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_radiation), and a cursory search seems to indicate that the methods of polarizing it and measuring its polarization are known.

With all these conditions fulfilled, I don't see any difference from the situation with the molecules and ordinary light.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I wonder if it's possible to formalise some concept of "maximising chirality", such that a single interaction between a chiral photon and a chirally-maximised object *would* be significantly different depending on the relative chiralities. With molecules this may be hard to investigate smoothly, but perhaps macroscopic objects could be more freely adjusted and studied.

Comment: Screw-shaped things like helicenes come to mind.

Comment: and some types of achiral liquid crystal forming molecules have chiral helical phases.

Comment: Human hand is a macroscopic object, even if there are billions, they will not rotate light. Optical rotation is a molecular phenomenon not a macroscopic phenomenon.

Comment: Microwave radiation is not exactly light.

Comment: Still *a lot* smaller than a macroscopic object.

Comment: How so? Its wavelength is rather macroscopic, as to me.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, My understanding has be smaller than the wavelength. Let us roughly say microwaves have 1 cm wavelength, in order to see microwave rotation, the objects have to less than that. See this linked paper,  they used springs to show optical rotation with microwaves but the springs were smaller than the center wavelength. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7775673https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7775673

Comment: Great! You have found the evidence that the effect does exist and can be measured for microwaves, after all! As for the size, why bother; just take a wavelength 10 times longer (those still would be microwaves).

Comment: The OP should not call it an "optical" rotation. Rotation of polarized long waves is more than century old phenomenon. Blocking of polarized radiowaves with wire "polarizer" is a nice demo in physics. Still a human living hand would not rotate microwave radiation. It will simply absorb it quite strongly. I have worked with microwave spectrometers, and trace of water is a headache.

Comment: Who said "living"? As for the rest, well, yeah, the OP's terminology needs correction in that the word "optical" typically refers to the visible light and not to the other ranges of the EM spectrum. Ditto for the word "light", BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The wavelength has to be comparable with the object size in order to see those effects. Your macroscopic hand will *not* rotate ordinary light even if you have millions hands around, because the wavelength of light is so small. Yes, it will scatter light as a large object. This idea of optical rotation by long wavelengths and by large objects was shown more than 100 years ago by J.C. Bose, using twisted pieces of jute (a type of rope made from plants). Bose was in India and jute was a common material there to play around.

See this article.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/115973?seq=1.

Comment: I think you got the the 'Bose's mixed up. The Bose whose you're referring to is JC Bose, who was the one who did many experiments with EM waves. The other Bose is SN Bose who made contributions to Quantum Mechanics.(Bose-Einstein)

Comment: You are right Milan. I corrected it.